# How to transform Dataset[(String, Seq[String])] to Dataset[(String, String)]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Probably this's simple problem, but I begin my adventure with spark.

**Problem**: I'd like to get following structure (Expected result) in spark. Now I have following structure.

> title1, {word11, word12, word13 ...} 
>   title2, {word12, word22, word23 ...}

Data are stored in Dataset[(String, Seq[String])]

**Excepted result** 
I would like to get Tuple [word, title]

> word11, {title1} 
>  word12, {title1}

**What I do** 
1. Make (title, seq[word1,word2,word,3])

```
docs.mapPartitions { iter =>
  iter.map {
     case (title, contents) => {
        val textToLemmas: Seq[String] = toText(....)
        (title, textToLemmas)
     }
  }
}
```

2. I tried use .map to transform my structure to Tuple, but can't do it.
3. I tried to iterate through all the elements, but then I can not return type

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
val result = dataSet.flatMap { case (title, words) => words.map((_, title)) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to call the `explode` function like this :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
dataset.withColumn("_2", explode("_2")).as[(String, String)]
```

Hope this help you, Best Regrads.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one offered a solution with Scala's **for-comprehension** (that gets "desugared" to `flatMap` and `map` as in [Yuval Itzchakov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086160/1305344)'s answer at compile time).

When you see a series of `flatMap` and `map` (possibly with `filter`) that's Scala's for-comprehension.

So the following:

```
val result = dataSet.flatMap { case (title, words) => words.map((_, title)) }
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
val result = for {
  (title, words) <- dataSet
  w <- words
} yield (w, title)
```

After all, that's why we enjoy flexibility of Scala, *isn't it?*